# Save Web Api response to an Xml Document

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-web-api

I have the following code to consume Web Api and get the response.

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:44522/");

        // Add an Accept header for XML format.
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
            new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/xml"));

        IEnumerable<Product> products = new List<Product>();

        HttpResponseMessage resp = client.GetAsync("api/admin").Result;
        if (resp.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            // Parse the response body. 
            products = resp.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<Product>>().Result;
        }
```

Here I am getting the products list. But instead of getting the products into a list, I want to write the response to an Xml Document.

Can somebody advise me on this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ReadAsByteArrayAsync()`:

```
var ms = new MemoryStream(resp.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result);
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(ms);
```

Comment: You can also do ReadAsStreamAsync and skip a step

Answer (score 0):

You can also try using something like http://restsharp.org/